# JavaFX Button is shown as selected when showing Stage

Tags: java, javafx

My button shows selected when first enter the stage, even select the second button, it automatically displays the first button being selected.

How to prevent the problem?

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am sorry because I don't know which part is wrong.

Comment: that's why you should read the referenced page ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid any control to be focused, if you for example focus a container on the `Scene` before showing the stage:

```
scene.getRoot().requestFocus();
```

Comment: haha:) tbh I was totally sure that he means that the first button is displayed as focused, but now I am not so sure anymore ... let's see ^^

Comment: DVarga you are correct. The problem solved with these codes: scene2 = new Scene(pane2); scene2.getRoot().requestFocus(); stage.setScene(scene2);

Comment: @WingKuiTsoi most probably you are doctoring on symptoms .. without a clear understanding what exactly went wrong and why the problem went away with your snippet you'll run into similar problems again and again ... just saying .. and kudos to the mind-reader <g>